# Implement AES/RES encryption decryption in OutSystems app

Tags: encryption, aes, outsystems

I have an app that calls some REST APIs. Without encryption/decryption, I have almost finished it but as now i have to implement the same as on server side, they will not accept non-encrypted requests.
Can you tell me how can this be achieved.

Comment: Request response will be encrypted during transit provided you use SSL/TLS (https). Is this not sufficient in your case. Please detail out the requirement in question.

Answer (score 2):

Check the CryptoAPI library. It allows you to encrypt/decrypt using AES and RSA. The CryptoAPI is the *de facto standard* library for encryption on the OutSystems platform.

Link: https://www.outsystems.com/forge/component/437/cryptoapi

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.outsystems.com/forge/component/129/twitter-connector

Twitter only accepts ciphered requests also, and we've implemented it in that connector.

Hope it helps